# Parameterize the find method in python using mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Files to upload will be like WFSIV0101202001.318.tar.gz,WFSIV0101202001.2624.tar.gz etc.

```
    INPUT_FILE_PATH = 'C:\Files to upload'
try:
    import os
    from google.cloud import storage
    import sys
    import pymongo
    import pymongo.errors
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
except:
    print("missing modules")
try:
    mongo_client = MongoClient(host="xyz.com", port=27017)
    Db = mongo_client['abcd']
    coll = Db['shopper_journey_sitedata']
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Connection failed")
date=[]
# Thirdpartyid=[]
input_files = os.listdir(INPUT_FILE_PATH)
# looping through input files
for input_file in input_files:
    x = input_file.split(".")
    date.append(x[0][5:13])
    tp_site_id = x[1]
    # print(tp_site_id)
    cur = coll.find({"third_party_site_id":tp_site_id})
    for doc in cur:
        print(doc)
```

Now i want to parameterize the find() method for every id, so that on each iteration i should get st_site_id ?

above code i tried but ist giving error as **"Datas:name error"**

Comment: Where is it occurring, what is tid and add all the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing

```
 coll.find({"third_party_site_id": { $in : 
       [318,2624,2621,2622,102,078]}})
```

If Tid is an array, then you could replace `318` in your query to `Tid[I]`

Comment: Thanks for the response Gibbs, yes TID is an array & it is dynamic. i tried giving as Tid[i] but its not working.

Comment: Can you add complete code to reproduce the issue and complete error trace also?

Comment: Gibbs : i have added full script above.

Comment: What is not working and where did you get that error

Comment: when i started writing the script at beginning it gave some error, now i have update it , right now error is not the issue. i just want to parameterize the find method.